# Handling hundreds of routes in Vert.x best practices

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, coroutine

Please have a look at the piece of code below. Now suppose i'll have hundreds of entity like "person". How would you code such a thing to get it clean, concise, efficient, well structured ? Tx

```
class HttpEntryPoint : CoroutineVerticle() {

    private suspend fun person(r: RoutingContext) {
        val res = vertx.eventBus().requestAwait<String>("/person/:id", "1").body()
        r.response().end(res)
    }

    override suspend fun start() {
        val router = Router.router(vertx)
        router.get("/person/:id").coroutineHandler { ctx -> person(ctx) }
        vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router)
            .listenAwait(config.getInteger("http.port", 8080))
    }

    fun Route.coroutineHandler(fn: suspend (RoutingContext) -> Unit) {
        handler { ctx ->
            launch(ctx.vertx().dispatcher()) {
                try {
                    fn(ctx)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    ctx.fail(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are concerned about? Are you concerned about having a very large, potentially unmanageable class once you have added many more endpoints? Our are you concerned about something else?

Comment: Hi PiRocks. Yes i am concerned having unmanageable class once i'll have added hundreds of endpoints

Comment: In `start`, you can pass the router object to another class/function. That way you could have separate classes, each responsible for separate groups of endpoints, and then your current class would just hold references to

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `subrouter`.

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sub_routers

From the top of my head:

```
override suspend fun start() {
    router.mountSubrouter("/person", personRouter(vertx)) 
    // x100 if you'd like
}
```

Then in your `PersonRouter.kt`:

```
fun personRouter(vertx: Vertx): Router {
    val router = Router.router(vertx)
    router.get("/:id").coroutineHandler { ctx -> person(ctx) }
    // More endpoints
    return router
}
```